# 'Cliente' object has no attribute 'marca'

Tags: python

I can add data to a list and display, but when I do the same with another class it fails to find the data.

code:

```py
class Lista:
    lista = []

    def agregar(self,objeto):

        self.lista.append(objeto)
        
    def eliminar(self, indice):
        self.lista.pop(indice)
        
    def modificar(self, indice, objeto):
        self.lista[indice] = objeto


from lista import Lista
class Auto(Lista):
    def __init__(self, marca, color, modelo):
        self.color = color
        self.marca = marca
        self.modelo = modelo

    def mostrarAutos(self):
        i=0
        for auto in self.lista:
            print(f"{i+0}  {auto.marca}  {auto.modelo}  {auto.color}  ")
            i+=1
```

Comment: `lista` is static. It will share a single mutable list between all instances

Comment: When you construct Auto, the color, marca and modelo values are never appended to lista in the superclass which, as @mousetail has already explained, is a class attribute rather than an instance attribute which is probably what you want

Comment: I guess you want `Auto.lista` to contain all instances of `Auto`, but (a) you never add `self` to that list in the constructor, and (b) there seems to be another subclass `Cliente` that _is_ added to that (same) `lista` (since it's static, as others have pointed out) which does then now have all those `Auto` attributes.